# Merge two array of hashes

Tags: arrays, ruby, hashmap

I have two arrays of hashes and want to do one from it

```
first = 
[{:frontman=>"aaa", :category=>"bbb", :subcategory=>nil, :detail=>nil},other hashes]


second = 
[{:__content__=>"aaa", :id=>"9096290", :frontman=>"aaa"},other hashes]
```

I want to have

one large array of hashes

```
[{:__content__=>"aaa", :id=>"9096290", :frontman=>"aaa", :category=>"bbb", :subcategory=>nil, :detail=>nil},other hashes]
```

i have tried it

```
(first+second).group_by{|h| h[:frontman]}.map{|k,v| v.reduce(:merge)}
```

but it doesn't work for me

Comment: I would consider this a risky approach as hash keys are unique, in your case both the first and second array contain a hash with the key ``:frontman``.

Comment: @NabeelAmjad i can remove  `:frontman` i added it only for `group_by` clause

Comment: This appears to be a pure Ruby question. If so, please remove the Rails tag. Having the Rails tag wastes time of readers who are only interested in Rails questions and may cause readers only interested in pure Ruby questions to skip the question.

Comment: @CarySwoveland  Rails seems to have some extensions to core classes such as that to [Hash](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_support_core_extensions.html#extensions-to-hash),  one may use those methods while proposing solution if it is Ruby problem but with Rails app

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use this way:

```
first.zip(second).map { |f, s| f.merge(s) }
#=> [{:frontman=>"aaa", :category=>"bbb", :subcategory=>nil, ...}]
```

Comment: uh,looks nice. But what if i have diffrent size of hashes in both array,or it never mind

Comment: @user, first array must has greater or equal size